# Add a blank row in DataGrid's view

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a drop down (**ComboBox**) of multiple tables. Each table is of **DataTable** type.
Then, I have a **DataGrid**, whose ItemsSource property is bound to the selected table from a ComboBox. I do not have a mapped class for the item itself because I don't know the table schema at compile time.
Below is my XAML code of the tool:

```xml
<Grid>
    <!-- Grid definitions -->
    <ComboBox...
                ItemsSource="{Binding Tables, Mode=OneWay}"
                DisplayMemberPath="Key"
                SelectedValuePath="Value"/>
    <DataGrid...
                CanUserAddRows="True"
                AutoGenerateColumns="True"
                ItemsSource="{Binding ActiveTable.DefaultView}" />
    <!-- Buttons to add/edit/remove/save records -->
</Grid>
```

Now, as you can see from XAML, I have a couple of buttons to operate over table data. My tables have a PrimaryKey set, which doesn't let me have null cells. I don't really need null cells in the beginning. The idea I'm trying to achieve is:

1. Create a new empty row and mark row background with Green. This should start editing the row and wait for user's input. Once user done typing the data, a command is stored in commands list (so changes visually appear in the table but items shouldn't be modified just yet).
2. As soon as user presses Apply button, unsaved changes should be committed to the table. So, if user added a new row, it should actually be added to the table and Green background should now change to the default.

Similar to the described Add scenario, user can select a row to remove, the row will be marked with Red colour but not actually removed just yet. Instead a remove command will be recorded and applied only after user presses Apply button. In case if user modifies the row, row should be recoloured to orange (for example) and edit command recorded when user has finished modifying the row. Once user presses Apply, the edit command should be actually applied.

Below is my code to handling commands (ViewModel):

```cs
private readonly List<DBCommand> _unsavedCommands;
public IDictionary<string, DataTable> Tables { get; private set; }
public DataTable ActiveTable { get; private set; }

...

private void AddRecord(DataGrid dataGrid)
{
    NewRowAdded?.Invoke(dataGrid, null);
    var command = DBCommand.Create(...);
    _unsavedCommands.Add(command);
}
```

And Code Behind:

```cs
private void ActiveTable_NewRowAdded(object sender, DataTableNewRowEventArgs e)
{
    int newItemIndex = dataGrid.Items.Count - 1;
    var item = dataGrid.Items[newItemIndex];
    dataGrid.ScrollIntoView(item);
    dataGrid.SelectedIndex = newItemIndex;
    dataGrid.BeginEdit();

    var row = (item as DataRowView).Row;
    row.BeginEdit();
}
```

The problem with the above code is that an object of type **NewItemPlaceholder** is created when I press Add record button and then tool crashes.
Can anyone point me to how to achieve desired behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was that I was creating a row programmatically and created row wasn't aligned with the table schema. I opted to use a default behaviour for creating new rows from the UI.